# What's the difference between np.divide(x, y) and x/y in Python3?

Tags: python, numpy

I recently found a bug in my code that I was able to fix by replacing `np.divide(x, y)` with `x / y`.

I was under the impression that np.divide(x, y) was equivalent to x / y (it says as much in the numpy documentation).

Is this a bug in numpy or is it expected behaviour?

As I said my immediate issue is solved so I'm not too worried about finding a fix, I am more curious to understand what's going on.

```py
import numpy as np


x1 = np.array([[281], [15831], [30280], [975], [313], [739], [252], [10364], [21480], [1447], [315], [772], [95], [2710], [7408], [215], [111], [158], [0], [88], [21], [661], [0], [0], [0], [5], [4], [0], [12], [0], [0], [50], [28], [0], [0], [272]])
x2 = np.array([[499], [6315], [33800], [580], [208], [464], [384], [3127], [19596], [2319], [218], [1740], [217], [411], [4250], [223], [406], [267], [2], [0], [16], [0], [0], [0], [0], [8], [3], [0], [18], [0], [1], [0], [41], [0], [0], [0]])
x3 = np.array([[507], [6180], [34005], [555], [200], [451], [390], [3024], [19492], [2425], [211], [1848], [223], [396], [4097], [224], [406], [282], [2], [0], [16], [0], [0], [0], [0], [8], [3], [0], [19], [0], [2], [0], [45], [0], [0], [0]])
x4 = np.array([[507], [6178], [34017], [554], [200], [451], [391], [3022], [19486], [2439], [210], [1865], [223], [396], [4089], [224], [406], [284], [2], [0], [16], [0], [0], [0], [0], [8], [3], [0], [19], [0], [2], [0], [46], [0], [0], [0]])

not_zero = (x1 + x2) != 0
x = np.divide(2*(x1 - x2)**2, x1 + x2, where=not_zero)
r = (2*(x1[not_zero] - x2[not_zero])**2) / (x1[not_zero] + x2[not_zero])
print("n1 =",x.max(),"\tt1 =", r.max())

not_zero = (x2 + x3) != 0
x = np.divide(2*(x2 - x3)**2, x2 + x3, where=not_zero)
r = (2*(x2[not_zero] - x3[not_zero])**2) / (x2[not_zero] + x3[not_zero])
print("n2 =",x.max(),"\tt2 =", r.max())

not_zero = (x3 + x4) != 0
x = np.divide(2*(x3 - x4)**2, x3 + x4, where=not_zero)
r = (2*(x3[not_zero] - x4[not_zero])**2) / (x3[not_zero] + x4[not_zero])
print("n3 =",x.max(),"\tt3 =", r.max())
```

*Output:*

```
n1 = 8177.933351395286  t1 = 8177.933351395286
n2 = 873842.0           t2 = 6.501672240802676
n3 = 1322.0             t3 = 0.15566927013196877
```

Python version: 3.7.6
Numpy version: 1.17.0

Comment: Can you add code that shows the problem more clearly (try to create an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))?

Comment: The output for each calculation should be the same. In the above example, n2!=t2 and n3!=t3 is the problem

Comment: Regarding usage of the `where` parameter of `np.divide`, the documentation says the following:  "Note that if an uninitialized out array is created via the default out=None, locations within it where the condition is False will remain uninitialized." You are using the default output array, and have situations where the condition is `False`. Maybe not related, but definitely bug in your code. (over here it generates some rather crazy results).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parameter `where = mask` without the parameter `out` is somewhat dangerous.  Without a target for the output, the function builds an `np.empty` array of the appropriate shape, and then replaces some subset of the empty array with the output data.

But `np.empty` isn't, well, empty.  It's just a random memory location that hasn't been initialized (so it still has any garbage data that existed in that memory block before).  So where `mask = False`, your output will be that leftover random garbage.  If that memory block happens to have binary garbage that can be encoded into a number bigger than the rest of your data, it end up being your `max` value.

You can mask out the garbage using `not_zero` as a mask again:

```
x = np.divide(2*(x1 - x2)**2, x1 + x2, where=not_zero)[not_zero]
```

or initialize your output array yourself:

```
x = np.zeros_like(x1)
np.divide(2*(x1 - x2)**2, x1 + x2, where = not_zero, out = x)
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you! This works and I now understand why it didn't before :)

Comment: This has nothing to do with garbage collection. The memory is properly allocated, but the contents aren't *initialized*.

Comment: @chepner improved the terminology.